# count of queries codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How I can get count of all queries in Codeigniter which are executing while program is running? (in benchmarks only memory usage && elapsed time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the profiler, you can do with this code:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

[See the docs for more info on profiler](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html)

Comment: I randomly stumbled upon this question, and it reminded me that CI does, in fact, have a neat profiler I had forgotten completely about! I've already found some pointless queries in the web app I'm working on that shouldn't have been running and the page load times have started dropping! Thanks! :D